# Apache configuration to access directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost

I'm on Ubuntu 9.10. My web application is in a directory on my /home/me/app . I want to configure Apache in such a way that I can access my app through a directory. For example:

People can access my machine through domain.com. What I would like to do is access my web application (located at /home/me/app) through a directory, using something like: domain.com/myapp.

How can I set up the apache configuration for this kind of behavior? Of course, I do not want to move all my application to /var/www/myapp.

The Alias directive did not solve my problem. If try to enter something like mydomain.com/recommender/somedir. It won't find anything. Because the alias only covers the "/recommender" path

What I would like, is something like a VirtualHost, but instead of pointing to a ServerName, I want to point to a directory name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Jumping on an old question here, but for posterity/searchers: a common method here is just to symlink `/home/me/app` to `/var/www/myapp`.  SSH in and run a quick

```
ln -s /home/me/app /var/www/myapp
```

It's not an apache config, but it's clean and does what you want it to.  This is assuming, of course, you have `/var/www/` set up as your webroot, which seems to be implied.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted is just an alias command in apache.conf:

`Alias /recommender /home/me/app`

Comment: please mark this as answered.

Comment: In fact, it did not resolve my issue. If try to enter something like mydomain.com/recommender/somedir. It won't find anything. Because the alias only covers the "/recommender" path

Comment: mod_rewrite or mod_userdir

Answer (score 0):

I would configure it to use [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) but that's me...